# How to download and backup all pacman and pacaur packages?

Tags: arch-linux, pacman, download, aur, pkgbuild

I would like to have an backup of all pacaur and pacman packages.

Example:
https://www.archlinux.org/packages/

How to download it all?

Answer (score 1):

You can download all `pacman` packages with `pacman -Ssq | xargs pacman -Swdd` or get the URLs with `pacman -Ssq | xargs pacman -Swpdd`.

- `-Ss` lists all packages
- `-q` only outputs the package name.
- `-Sw` only downloads the packages`
- `-dd` ignores all dependencies
- `-p` prints the targets.

`pacman` will download them to `/var/cache/pacman/pkg` but you can change it by changeing `CacheDir` in `/etc/pacman.conf`.

AUR packages need to be built, so you would have to build every single AUR package.
Some PKGBUILDs (e.g.[aur](https://aur.archlinux.org/cgit/aur.git/tree/PKGBUILD?h=aur)) just install everything with sudo so you would have to check every PKGBUILD.

Comment: Really thx!! You are a master! There is an way to download pacaur unbuilded?

Comment: I would like to download all pacaur even if it is unbuilded. I'm doing a backup of the internet.

Comment: It would be hard, because PKGBUILDs contain links to the source files. Some source files are multiple gigabytes big and others may not be available anymore. The source files could include scripts, which could download other files.

Comment: Thx! Your knowledge is gratifying.